# Product Flat Data Error - PHP Fatal Error: Call to member function reindexAll() on a non-object

Tags: magento, indexing

I was having a problem with the row limit in MySQL because of the amount of attributes in a Magento install, so I put together an extension that extended the 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer' class to rewrite the char limit to 64 using the following code.

```
protected function _MySQLCharLimit()
{
    if (!$this->_isFlatTableExists($store)) {

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$tableNameQuote} (n";

        foreach ( $columns as $field => $fieldProp ) {
            if ( $fieldProp['type'] == "varchar(255)" )
            $fieldProp['type'] = "varchar(64)";
                $sql .= sprintf( "  %s,n",
                $this->_sqlColunmDefinition( $field, $fieldProp ) );
        }
        foreach ($addIndexes as $indexName => $indexProp) {
            $sql .= sprintf(' ADD %s,',
            $this->_sqlIndexDefinition( $indexName, $indexProp ) );
        }
        $sql = rtrim($sql, ",");
        $sql = str_replace( "varchar(255)","varchar(64)",$sql );
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query( $sql );
    }
}
```

Which I got from here http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/mysql-limitations-on-the-flat-catalogue-in-magento/.

After trying to reindex I noticed that it sent me to a blank page and when I clicked back the 'Product Flat Data' index was stuck on processing.

I ran the indexer.php from the 'shell' folder via SSH and it reported this error:

PHP Fatal Error: Call to member function reindexAll() on a non-object in Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php on line 296

Has anyone got any idea on what has gone wrong or how I can rectify this? Thanks.

**EDIT:** Full Code

```
<?php
class GDModules_MySQLCharLimit_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer
{
    public function mySQLCharLimit()
    {
        if (!$this->_isFlatTableExists($store)) {

            $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$tableNameQuote} (n";

            foreach ( $columns as $field => $fieldProp ) {
                if ( $fieldProp['type'] == "varchar(255)" )
                $fieldProp['type'] = "varchar(64)";
                    $sql .= sprintf( "  %s,n",
                    $this->_sqlColunmDefinition( $field, $fieldProp ) );
            }
            foreach ($addIndexes as $indexName => $indexProp) {
                $sql .= sprintf(' ADD %s,',
                $this->_sqlIndexDefinition( $indexName, $indexProp ) );
            }
            $sql = rtrim($sql, ",");
            $sql = str_replace( "varchar(255)","varchar(64)",$sql );
            $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query( $sql );
        }
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- The root node for Magento module configuration -->
<config>

    <!--
    The module's node contains basic
    information about each Magento module
    -->
    <modules>

        <!--
        This must exactly match the namespace and module's folder
        names, with directory separators replaced by underscores
        -->
        <GDModules_MySQLCharLimit>

            <!-- The version of our module, starting at 0.0.1 -->
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </GDModules_MySQLCharLimit>
    </modules>

    <!-- Configure our module's behaviour in the global scope -->
    <global>
        <!-- Defining models -->
        <models>
            <catalog_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_flat_indexer>GDModules_MySQLCharLimit_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer</product_flat_indexer>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Your rewrite in config.xml is misconfigured.  Magento can't instantiate the resource model it needs to.

Comment: Ah OK, what should I be doing?

Comment: Using this <global>
     <!-- Defining models -->
     <models>
         <catalog_resource>
             <rewrite>
              <product_flat_indexer>GDModules_MySQLCharLimit_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer</product_flat_indexer>
    </rewrite>
         </catalog_resource>
     </models>
    </global>

Comment: For starters I'd see if you can instantiate your resource model class directly.  $foo = new GDModules_MySQLCharLimit_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer; var_dump(get_class($foo));  Most commonly the class is in the wrong directory and/or there's a typo in the class name.

Comment: I'm not sure it's that as even if I disable and remove my extension it still has the error.

Comment: Tell a lie, no it doesn't. God I'm stumped as I can't see any typos or errors.

Comment: Again, can you instantiate a GDModules_MySQLCharLimit_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer object directly?

Comment: Where should I do this though, I'm pretty new to this stuff?

Comment: Anywhere you can run PHP code in Magento.